# Using multiple iterators in map function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which uses a for loop find the starting position of a char in a 2d list made up of characters.

```
def findStartPos(char, arr):
    for y, sublist in enumerate(arr):
        pos = []
        if char in sublist:
            x = arr[y].index(char)
            pos.append(x)
            pos.append(y)
            return pos
    return -1
```

How can I translate this with a map function? If possible. Concidering I'm iterating both y which is arr[y] and sublist which is arr[y][x]. Also if there's any other way to optimize the code would help.

I've not tried anything yet as I don't know how to move forward.

Comment: Note: `arr[y]` is the same as `sublist`.

Comment: Have a look at the built in function `list.find()`. It does most of what you want to do.

Comment: Can you give an example input? And the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `map` to achieve the desired result. I minimally changed your original function to give you an idea of how to achieve this.

```
from functools import partial

def mapper(char, idx_arr):
    idx, subarr = idx_arr
    if char in subarr:
        x = sublist.index(char)
        return x, idx
    return -1, -1. # same return type for consistency

arr = [["f", "d"], ["d", "c"]]
char = "c"

p = partial(mapper, char)
next(filter(lambda x: sum(x) > -1, map(p, enumerate(arr))))
>> (1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented this already but here's a code snippet that might help you a bit. I sticked mostly to your variable naming with a few improvements:

```
def findStartPos(char, arr):
    for y, sublist in enumerate(arr):
        x = sublist.find(char) # finds the first instance of char in sublist and returns its index, if it can't find any it returns -1
        if x != -1:
            return [x, y] # here you can just return a list in stead of creating an empty list and appending x and y, this looks cleaner
    return -1
```

Now I'm not sure if it makes sense to implement a map function here, but maybe others can help on that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for optimization instead of just an application of dictionary?

**Question time!** Is there any algorithm to search a char in an array faster than the linear search? The answer is usually no unless the array is sorted. Hence, you have to check all the indexes for your query. There is no faster solution. Converting your matrix into list of sets doesnot optimize it either since the list to set conversion is of O(n) time complexity.

Again, if you have a single matrix but multiple queries, you can preprocess the matrix and store the location(indices) of each element, for each unique element in a dictionary as you traverse across the matrix and you have to do this **only once** for all the queries just by preprocessing once.

My implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict #to make life easier
def preprocess(matrix):
  dic_to_store_index=defaultdict(list)
  for i in range(len(matrix)):
          for m in range(len(matrix[i])):
                    dic_to_store_index[matrix[i][m]].append((i,m)) #Storing tuples of indexes
                    
  return dic_to_store_index

def find(dic,char):
  return dic[char][0]

matrix=[[5,6,5,4,2,4,5],[2,2,2,2],[2,7,2,1]] #Your matrix here
dic=preprocess(matrix) #preprocess only once for  all queries
char=2 #lets find first occurance of  2 in this matrix
print(find(dic,char)) # 0{1) operation
char=7 #another query
print(find(dic,char)) #O(1) complexity and no need to traverse matrix
```

[image]

In this way, you don't have to iterate through the whole matrix for each query.